# Remove JSTOR ID from Biber bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use Zotero for my references and, at some point, a whole set of JSTOR ID's started appearing in my biber bibliography. I compile using pdflatex and biber.

[image: JSTOR ID showing in bibliography]

How can I get rid of these ugly JSTOR references? I assume it's to do with the `eprinttype` and `eprint` fields which Zotero appends to my entries.

---

## foo.tex

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,
    style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2,
    uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{% Get rid of the unwanted "note" field
  \clearfield{note}%
  \clearlist{language}%
}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}
    \textcite{krugman_scale_1980-2} 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

## foo.bib

```
@article{krugman_scale_1980-2,
  eprinttype = {jstor},
  eprint = {1805774},
  title = {Scale {{Economies}}, {{Product Differentiation}}, and the {{Pattern}} of {{Trade}}},
  volume = {70},
  issn = {0002-8282},
  number = {5},
  journaltitle = {The American Economic Review},
  date = {1980},
  pages = {950--959},
  keywords = {dixit-stiglitz-ces},
  author = {Krugman, Paul},
  file = {/home/rob/Zotero/storage/VD5MZDJM/Krugman - 1980 - Scale Economies, Product Differentiation, and the .pdf}
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use any other `eprint`s, you can use `eprint=false` (that will also include arXiv, though). If you want to get rid of JSTOR specifically you can use Biber sourcemapping for that.

Comment: @moewe That did it. Thanks. If you'd like to answer the question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

1. The `eprint=false` option. This will disable all `eprint`s, not just JSTOR. In particular this will also suppress references to the popular arXiv.
2. Get rid of JSTOR `eprint`s in `\AtEveryBibitem`

   ```
   \AtEveryBibitem{%
     \iffieldequalstr{eprinttype}{jstor}
       {\clearfield{eprint}}
       {}}
   ```
3. Use Biber's sourcemapping to target JSTOR

   ```
   \DeclareSourcemap{
      \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
          \step[fieldsource=eprinttype, match={jstor}, final]
          \step[fieldset=eprint, null]
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: This is a brilliant answer.